# Gentoo running unknown scheduler

Tags: cron, gentoo, scheduling

I inherited management of a Gentoo based server (Gentoo Base System release 2.3, 4.4.26-gentoo) that is invoking a number of php scripts each night but I can't figure out how. I don't see them referenced in any user's crontab and I don't see references in /etc/cron.* dirs.

Can anyone advise where to start looking for alternate scheduling methods?

Comment: Have you checked `/etc/crontab` file?

Comment: That's exactly where they were. Thanks. I'll edit and sudo crontab /etc/crontab.